# Discord.NET Users playing the same game

Tags: c#, discord.net

I am trying to create a command that returns the number of guild members that are currently playing a specified game.

*Example (! is my prefix)*: !playing League of Legends.

If there are 5 members playing League of Legends, output:

`There are 5 users currently playing League of Legends.`

I set up the following, from debugging I was able to pick up that `v.Game.toString()` returns the correct string but for some reason the if statement does not trigger. It also catches an exception that is thrown whenever members are not playing a game (I assumed it's null?), is there a workaround for that? Why does this not count how many members are playing a certain game?

```
[Command("playing")]
    public async Task playingGame(params string[] s)
    {
        string gameName = "";
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            gameName += s[i] + " ";
        }

        await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Looking for: " + gameName);

        var u = Context.Guild.Users;
         foreach (var v in u)
         {
            await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("v = " + v.ToString());
            try
            {
                await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(v.Game.ToString());
                if (v.Game.ToString().ToLower().Equals(gameName.ToLower()))
                {
                    count++;
                    await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Found match, count = " + count);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Exception throw caught");
            }
         }

        if (count > 1) {
            await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("There are " + count + " users currently playing " + gameName + ".");
        }
        else if (count == 1)
        {
            await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("There is " + count + " user currently playing " + gameName + ".");
        }
        else if (count == 0)
        {
            await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("No one is currently playing " + gameName + ".");
        }
    }
```

This is the exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: Argument cannot be blank
Parameter name: Content
at Discord.Preconditions.NotNullOrEmpty(String obj, String name, String msg)
at Discord.API.DiscordRestApiClient.<CreateMessageAsync>d__77.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

Pic of where if statement should trigger (username blocked for privacy reasons):

[image]

Comment: can you share the exception?

Comment: @aloisdg Added the exception message and a picture of where the if statement should have triggered.

Comment: I know the string is null, because they're not playing a game so it's not initialized. My primary concern is that the if statement is not triggering,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to have `params string[] s` for the game parameter. Just use the `Remainder` attribute.

I have also simplified this code *alot* :

```
    [Command("playing")]
    public async Task GetUsersPlaying([Remainder]string game)
    {
        await Context.Message.DeleteAsync();

        var users = Context.Guild.Users.Where(x => x.Game.ToString() == game).Distinct().Select(x => x.Username);
        var count = users.Count();

        var SeparatedList = string.Join(", ", users);

        string message;
        if (count > 1)
            message = $"There are {count} users playing {game}. [{SeparatedList}]";
        else if (count == 1)
           message = $"There is {count} user playing {game}. [{SeparatedList}]";
        else
            message = $"There is no one playing {game}.";

        await  Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(message);
    }
```

Comment: This is elegant, using Linq. How would I go about creating a list of those x member names in order to display a list of players after the sentence?

Comment: You could also get the count from `UserList` instead of having a totally different variable.